# Contact Form 7 - How do I open a URL with one of the input values

Tags: wordpress, url, contact-form-7

In Contact Form 7 I am currently using this for the additional settings:

on_sent_ok: "location = '`http://example.com/`';"

But how do I open the url with a value from one of the fields? For example:

http://join.me/   then the number that the client inputs..

I am using this so that people can go to my site and open a join.me meeting from my homepage.

Comment: I would not be using contact form 7 for this. You could accomplish it with a simple form coded with javascript. Do you have any experience working with the template files?

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically change `on_sent_ok` without needs of js, you can use the action `wpcf7_before_send_mail`.

In this little example extract from a class I've done (I've remove many thing, but the method is here), you'll need to configure your form with a field called pagetoredirect.

```
public function __construct(){

     add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', array($this, 'mail_send_redirection'));

}

public static function mail_send_redirection($contact_form){

    $options = get_option('bcf7u_general_settings');
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ($submission) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data(); 
        $redirection_page_id = (empty($redirection_form_id)) ? $options['bcf7u_thank_you_url'] : $posted_data['pagetoredirect'];

        $contact_form->skip_mail = false;

        $contact_form->set_properties(array('additional_settings' => "on_sent_ok: \"location.replace('" . get_permalink($redirection_page_id) . "/?nonce=" . $nonce . "');\""));

     }
}
```

Hope it helps